# Why do we need Address Resolution Protocol?

Tags: networking, network-programming, communication, mac-address, arp

I understand the mechanism of ARP but I am wondering why do we use it even if we have the recipient's IP address? Isn't it enough to rely on the recipient's IP address to send packets instead of taking extra steps of finding its matching MAC address?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the network layer sends *to* a MAC address. Somebody has to do it.

Comment: please read more about OSI layers specifically with layer2 and layer3 check this link i hope that help to understanding well why mac address https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874176/swich-table-in-case-of-crc-error/30884001#30884001

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An IP address is a layer-3 address.  Layer-3 packets get encapsulated into layer-2 frames, and layer-2 also has addressing (MAC addresses) which needs to be supplied.  ARP (Address *Resolution* Protocol) *resolves* the layer-3 IP address to a layer-2 MAC address so that the layer-3 packet can be encapsulated into a layer-2 frame which is then sent out the layer-1 interface.